# Navigate TaskDialogPage after asynchronous call

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await, taskdialog

I need to navigate a `TaskDialogPage` to another after an asynchronous operation has completed. Here's my code

```
TaskDialogPage page = new()
{
    //...
}

TaskDialogPage completedPage = new()
{
    //...
}

page.Created += async (_, _) =>
{
    await DoSomethingThatTakesTime().ConfigureAwait(false);
    page.Navigate(completedPage); // NotSupportedException - Illegal thread call 
};
```

I could use `Control.Invoke()` method :

```
page.Invoke(() => page.Navigate(completedPage))
```

But `TaskDialogPage` doesn't inherit from `Control` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await DoSomethingThatTakesTime().ConfigureAwait(true);
```

Got it. `ConfigureAwait` specifies wether there should be an attempt to get back to the original context, i.e. , the UI context. Even though `ConfigureAwait(true)` is the default and specified implicitly, I think this better captures the intent.